# how can i list all packages which ere installed by me in centos without dependencies

Tags: linux, centos, yum

If i execute

`yum list installed` then i get all the pacakges including dependencies packagaes.

but i want to find those packages which were installed by me manually by typing command

`yum install pkgname`

is it possible in centos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this command to see your history with command lines:

```
yum history info '*'|grep 'Command Line'
```

Example:

```
$ yum history info '*'|grep 'Command Line'
Command Line   : install xterm
Command Line   : install xclock
...
```

Run without grep and using less to see the dates, etc...